# FindToolWindow Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am implementing a ShowToolWindow() function in a visual studio extension project that displays a toolwindow on click of a button.
The following code works:

```
private void ShowToolWindow()
{
  IVsUIShell vsUIShell = (IVsUIShell)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
  IVsWindowFrame frame;
  Guid WindowGuid = new Guid("48d81433-5d5c-4d4c-a174-d8e620c0e0a8");
  vsUIShell.FindToolWindow((uint)__VSFINDTOOLWIN.FTW_fForceCreate, ref WindowGuid, out frame);
  frame.Show();
}
```

However, the following code does not work

```
private void ShowToolWindow1()
{
  this.package = new ToolWindowPackage()/*Package that provides the window*/;
  var window = (MyToolWindow)this.package.FindToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), 0, true); /*This line throws an exception*/
  IVsWindowFrame frame = window.Frame;
  frame.show();
}
```

In this case the FindToolWindow throws the following exception

*Activated  Event   Time    Duration    Thread
    Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll ("The service 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsUIShell' must be installed for this feature to work.  Ensure that this service is available."). Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll ("The service 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsUIShell' must be installed for this feature to work.  Ensure that this service is available.")*

It seems it is not calling the Package.FindToolWindow, but rather the IVsUIShell.FindToolWindow. How should I resolve this.

I am asking this question because I need to get a handle of the ToolWindowPane. Therefore even though the first way shows the toolwindow correctly it is not suffice. An alternative solution to this question, could someone tell me how to get a handle of the ToolWindowPane Through the first method?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new instance of ToolWindowPackage by yourself. You should use an existing package instance instantiated by Visual Studio.